# How to View Data from MySql Database to SQL Server Kentico?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-services, kentico

I have MySQL Database that Contain data i want to view in KenticoCMS 7.0 
since there is no support from Kentico to MySQL  DataBase , i have change the Connection string inside Web.config file

from : SQL Server Connection String 
to : MySQL Connection String

and the result was kicking out to configuration Page

```
<add name="CMSConnectionString" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;database=SaDb;server=.\SQLExpress;user id=sa;password=P@ssw0rd;Current Language=English;Connection Timeout=240;" />
```

to reconfigure Database Again like first time i install Kentico

```
<add name="MySQLConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" />
```

is there is any idea about view(just view) mySql data without convert it to SQL Server DB
or making Web service to do this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the main connection string of Kentico database. It results in new database installation as you described. In your situation you will have to develop a custom code to connect to MySql database. Creating a custom webpart may be a good way. Basically what you need to do:

1. Create a custom webpart - [how to do it](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?developing_web_parts.htm).
2. Install MySql drivers - copying assemblies from MySql connector-net into your website bin should be enough. Package can be downloaded [here](http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/mysql/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.7.4-noinstall.zip).
3. Connect to MySql database - [tutorial here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html).
4. Retrieve and display data in a way you want.